# Having issues finding an website element in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm building a bookerbot for fun, and it's my first time using Selenium. I'm really stumped for why I keep getting the following error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="root"]/main/section[2]/div/button"}
```

The sample website I'm trying this is a workout class site: https://www.barrys.com/my-account/

I'm simply trying to click on the login button, so using the following command:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5000).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/main/section[2]/div/button'))
    ).click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/main/section[2]/div/button')
```

Comment: Xpath has a bit of a learning curve. Might be better off with a css selector, as in `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-test-button=log-in]')`

Comment: Still getting the same error unfortunately. I also checked the page for iframes and I don't think that is the issue?

Comment: hmmm are you sure, there are problems? because from the exception and the code it seems like you do click it. It goes to login page, but the xpath is no longer valid there so `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/main/section[2]/div/button')` this code will fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `iframe` within which the <kbd>Login</kbd> button exist. So, before clicking on the login button, you need to switch into the `iframe`, then perform the action. Try the below code:

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[1]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
WebDriverWait(driver, 5000).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/main/section[2]/div/button'))
).click()
```

Comment: This is correct - I had missed the iframe, and by switching to the right iframe, it allowed me to find the element via the XPATH.